# RestFulClient CRUDRepository Implementation

Tags: spring-boot, crud, resttemplate

I am using SpringBoot to write web service client. How to use CRUDRepository inside the client?  I have to save the data from the webservice to a database table? How do I get the handle to BookRepository inside my client?

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<BooksStage, Long> {}     

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Books[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/booksList", Books[].class); 
Books[] books=responseEntity.getBody(); 
if(books!=null){
log.info("booksreceived -"+books.length);            
for (Books c : books){
//Insert into database
}
}
```

Comment: What actually do you need to store? Your created repository for 'BooksStage' but you're receiving 'Books' objects from the REST call.

Comment: Book information need to be stored. The entity name is BooksStage. Do they need to match? How to get handle to BookRepository inside my client code?                                                                                                       for (Books c : books){
//Insert into database
}

Answer (score 0):

1) Interface BookRepository shall be annotated with @Repository. You should autowire interface BookRepository in your Web Service Client class.

2) The RestTemplate shall be inside a Web Service Client class annotated with @Service

3) Since your entity name is BooksStage, you should only save entity of type BooksStage (and not Books).

```
@Repository    
    public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<BooksStage, Long> {

}


@Service
public class MyWebServiceClient{

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepo; 

    public boolean updateSomeBook() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<BooksStage[]> responseEntity =     
           restTemplate.getForEntity ("http://localhost:8080/booksList", Books[].class); 
        BooksStage[] books=responseEntity.getBody(); 
        if(books!=null){
        log.info("booksreceived -"+books.length);            

        for (BooksStage c : books){
               bookRepo.save(c);
        }
        return true;
    }  
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "books_stage")
public class BooksStage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    //other related fields 

}
```